# Kotlin how to access main class variable from other class

Tags: kotlin

This is my main class:

```
package com.example.myProject

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.GridLayout
import androidx.core.view.marginLeft
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var level : Int = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //...
        var piece = Piece(this, 50)
    }
}
```

I also have second class:

```
data class Piece(
    var con: Context,
    var size : Int
) {

    init {
        //...
        //here I want to increment attribute level of the main class
        con.level++
    }
}
```

However, I can't access this attribute from there, even though I sent context as a parameter. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? Why not adding one on the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Context` class doesn't have a `level` attribute, even though the concrete type `MainActivity` does. So take a reference to a `MainActivity` instead:

```
data class Piece(
    var con: MainActivity,
    var size : Int
) {
```

This creates a circular dependency between `MainActivity` and `Piece`, so it could be considered a code smell. Without more context, it's hard to say what a better solution would look like.